# While/if loop giving me trouble (beginner)

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

I have been trying to make my first "solo" python program, its a calculator where you pick what kind of formula you want it to calculate and then input the variables needed. I got issues with my while/for loop, when i run the program i get the correct menu: menu(), and then when I choose my next menu by inputting 1 i correctly get the "v_menu" however if I input 2, which should get me the "m_menu", I instead just get the v_menu like I would if I typed in a 1.

I hope my explanation made sense, im still very new to all of this. Appreciate any help I can get, been breaking my head over this for atleast one hour or so..

Cheers, and heres my code:
     # coding=utf-8

```
#Menues
def menu():
    print "Choose which topic you want in the list below by typing the corresponding number\n"
    print "\t1) virksomhedsøkonomi\n \t2) matematik\n"
    return raw_input("type the topic you want to pick\n >>")


def v_menu():
    print "Choose which topic you want in the list below by typing the corresponding number"
    print "\t1) afkastningsgrad\n \t2) overskudsgrad\n \t3) aktivernes omsætningshastighed\n \t4)                          Egenkapitalens forrentning\n \t5) return to main menu\n"
    return raw_input("Type the topic you want to pick\n >>")

def m_menu():
    print "Choose which topic you want in the list below by typing the corresponding number"
    print "\t1) omregn Celsius til Fahrenheit\n \t2) omregn Fahrenheit til Celsius\n"
    return raw_input("Type the topic you want to pick\n >>")

    # - Mat -

#Celsius to Fahrenheit
def c_to_f():
    c_temp = float(raw_input("Enter a temperatur in Celsius"))
    #Calculates what the temperatur is in Fahrenheit
    f_temp = c_temp * 9 / 5 + 32
    #Prints the temperatur in Fahrenheit
    print (str(c_temp) + " Celsius is equal to " + str(f_temp) + " Fahrenheit")


#Fahrenheit to Celsius
def f_to_c(): 
    f_temp = float(raw_input("Enter a temperatur in Fahrenheit"))
    #Calculates what the temperatur is in celsius
    c_temp = (f_temp - 32) * (float(100) / 180)
    #Prints the temperatur in celsius
    print (str(f_temp) + " Fahrenheit is equal to " + str(c_temp) + " Celsius")


#Program
loop = 1
choice = 0



while loop == 1:
    choice = menu()

    if choice == "1" or "1)":
        v_menu()

    elif choice == "2" or "2)":
        m_menu()
        if choice == "1":
            c_to_f()
        elif choice == "2":
            f_to_c()

    loop = 0
```

Comment: I just edited a few mistakes, should be at the bottom of my code segment? Starts with. While loop == 1:

Comment: Appreciate the quick answers, will do my best to return and answer someone elses questions once I get a bit better at this ;)

Comment: `if choice in {"1","1)"}`

Comment: ^^ty, going to change it to that instead, saves quite a bit of space since I want to add some more valid inputs

Comment: no worries, set lookups are `0(1)` so in larger data sets the are a good way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in your if statements: if choice == "1" or "1)":

What you really need is: if choice == "1" or choice == "1)":

Everything after the or gets evaluated as another expression. You're saying "if choice is equal to one or if one exists."

"1)" evaluates to "true" in this instance, so you'll always hit that branch.

Comment: Ahh! Thankyou! Dangit, I even remember reading that rule, so silly how the issue always seems so obvious once someone tells you.

Comment: The preferred method for this in Python is `if choice in {"1", "1)"}:`.

Comment: Good point, Rick! OP: the parens there just mean that it is a tuple. There's nothing special, the same syntax would work for a list or a dictionary as well!

Comment: I actually edited it to be a `set` before seeing your comment about it being a tuple. I have been told using a `set` is superior inside of `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here;

```
if choice == "1" or "1)":
    v_menu()

elif choice == "2" or "2)":
```

You have to write them like;

```
if choice == "1" or choice == "1)":
        v_menu()

elif choice == "2" or choice == "2)":
```

Otherwise, all the time your if statement is `True`. And if first `if` statement is `True`, then your `elif` statement is not going to work. That's why you can't call `v_menu()`